# Place a legend for each facet_wrap grid in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, facet, facet-wrap

I have this data frame:

```
x <- data.frame(
  Date = factor(rep(
    c("12/1/2011", "1/2/2012", "2/1/2012", "2/10/2012", "2/13/2012"),
    3
  )),
  Server = factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 5L)),
  FileSystem = factor(c(
    "/", "/var", "tmp", "/db", "/app", "C:", "D:", "F:", "/restore",
    "G:", "/", "/tmp", "/data", "/Storage", "/database"
  )),
  PercentUsed = c(
    60L, 50L, 90L, 86L, 90L, 67L, 67L, 34L, 89L, 56L, 90L, 78L,
    67L, 34L, 12L
  )
)
x
#>         Date Server FileSystem PercentUsed
#> 1  12/1/2011      A          /          60
#> 2   1/2/2012      A       /var          50
#> 3   2/1/2012      A        tmp          90
#> 4  2/10/2012      A        /db          86
#> 5  2/13/2012      A       /app          90
#> 6  12/1/2011      B         C:          67
#> 7   1/2/2012      B         D:          67
#> 8   2/1/2012      B         F:          34
#> 9  2/10/2012      B   /restore          89
#> 10 2/13/2012      B         G:          56
#> 11 12/1/2011      C          /          90
#> 12  1/2/2012      C       /tmp          78
#> 13  2/1/2012      C      /data          67
#> 14 2/10/2012      C   /Storage          34
#> 15 2/13/2012      C  /database          12
```

I would like to put a legend right next to each `facet_wrap` grid, its own `FileSystem`:

When I do this, it puts the legend on the side of the plot for all of the `FileSystem`. Is it possible to put `FileSystem` belong to each server next to each grid?

```
ggplot(x, aes(Date, PercentUsed, group=1, colour=FileSystem)) + 
     geom_jitter(size=0.5) + geom_smooth(method="loess", se=T) + 
     facet_wrap(~Server, ncol=1)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Meh, @joran beat me to it (my `gridExtra` was out of date but took me 10 minutes to realize it). Here's a similar solution, but this one skins the cat generically by levels in `Server`.

```
library(gridExtra)
out <- by(data = x, INDICES = x$Server, FUN = function(m) {
      m <- droplevels(m)
      m <- ggplot(m, aes(Date, PercentUsed, group=1, colour = FileSystem)) + 
         geom_jitter(size=2) + geom_smooth(method="loess", se=T)
   })
do.call(grid.arrange, out)

# If you want to supply the parameters to grid.arrange
do.call(grid.arrange, c(out, ncol=3))
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I didn't realize that `droplevels()` had a method for `data.frame`s. That's handy!

Comment: Is there a neat way to force alignment, i.e. keep plot area width same? Prescribe legend width?

Comment: @mlt consider moving the legend to the top of the first figure and remove it from the rest.

Comment: Indeed I ended up moving all legends to top in a meanwhile. I can't use a single legend as they unique per plot. Though it would be nice to know if there is a way to prescribe widths.

Comment: @mlt consider making a new question, although AFAIK, it's not possible (it's possible to define margins, though).

Comment: @mlt, check out my suggestions below.

Answer (score 34):

The best way to do this is with the **gridExtra** package:

```
library(gridExtra)

xs <- split(x,f = x$Server)
p1 <- ggplot(xs$A,aes(x = Date,y = PercentUsed,group = 1,colour = FileSystem)) + 
        geom_jitter(size=0.5) + 
        geom_smooth(method="loess", se=T) + 
        facet_wrap(~Server, ncol=1)

p2 <- p1 %+% xs$B
p3 <- p1 %+% xs$C

grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3)
```

[image]

Comment: I should note that you made the points very small in `geom_jitter` and I'm not sure why, but I left it as is. The points are there, but hard to see.

Comment: I am a bit intrigued with the `%+%` operator. Can you please explain what it does?

Comment: @Legend It's a way to make a ggplot object "modular" in the sense that you can use it to simply drop in a new data frame, but use all the same geom specifications from a previous plot. Of course, it will only work if the column names all match, and if you haven't used any _other_ data frames in other layers.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your prompt response. This is such a fantastic way of re-using the objects!

Comment: @joran how can you make each plot in the grid take equal space so that their x ticks align?

Comment: @lgd It requires some work. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26159495/324364) (and the links therein) for some ideas.

Comment: @lgd, a couple of suggestions in my answer below to align the plot space properly.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using facets, we could make a list of plots per group, then use *cowplot::plot_grid* for plotting. Each will have it's own legend:

```
# make list of plots
ggList <- lapply(split(x, x$Server), function(i) {
  ggplot(i, aes(Date, PercentUsed, group = 1, colour = FileSystem)) + 
    geom_jitter(size = 2) +
    geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = TRUE)})

# plot as grid in 1 columns
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = ggList, ncol = 1,
                   align = 'v', labels = levels(x$Server))
```

---

As suggested by @Axeman, we could add labels using `facet_grid(~Server)`, instead of `labels = levels(x$Server)`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I liked @joran's answer and provide a couple of options based off of their code as a starting point. **Both options address the issue of mis-aligned facets.**

#### Legends outside facets

If you choose a monospaced font for your legend items, you can use `str_pad` to add padding on the right-hand side of all legend entries, forcing the length of each to be consistent.

If you're willing to use a monospaced font, this is a quick fix.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)
library(stringr)

l <- max(nchar(as.character(x$FileSystem)))
mylevels <- as.character(levels(x$FileSystem))
mylevels <- str_pad(mylevels, width = l, side = "right", pad = " ")
x <- mutate(x, FileSystem = factor(str_pad(FileSystem, width = l, side = "right", pad = " "),
            levels = mylevels))
windowsFonts("Lucida Sans Typewriter" = windowsFont("Lucida Sans Typewriter"))
xs <- split(x,f = x$Server)
p1 <- ggplot(xs$A,aes(x = Date,y = PercentUsed,group = 1,colour = FileSystem)) + 
  geom_jitter(size=0.5) + 
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=T) + 
  facet_wrap(~Server, ncol=1) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(family = "Lucida Sans Typewriter"))

p2 <- p1 %+% xs$B
p3 <- p1 %+% xs$C

grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3)
```

[image]

#### Legends inside facets

If you don't mind legends inside each facet, you can add extra space to each facet with the "expand" argument inside `scale` call:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- mutate(x, Date = as.Date(as.character(Date), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
xs <- split(x,f = x$Server)
p1 <- ggplot(xs$A,aes(x = Date,y = PercentUsed,group = 1,colour = FileSystem)) + 
  geom_jitter(size=0.5) + 
  scale_x_date(expand = expansion(add = c(5, 20)),
               date_labels = "%d-%m-%Y") +
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=T) + 
  facet_wrap(~Server, ncol=1) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.5))

p2 <- p1 %+% xs$B
p3 <- p1 %+% xs$C

grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Besides `gridExtra` and `cowplot` there's, also `patchwork` in the game now. Hence you can do the following:

```r
require(ggplot2)
require(patchwork)
# split
dfs = split(df, f = df$Server)
# apply ggplot function and write to list
gg_l = lapply(dfs, function(x) {
  ggplot(x, aes(x = Date,y = PercentUsed, group = 1, colour = FileSystem)) + 
    geom_jitter(size = 0.5) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = TRUE) + 
    facet_wrap(~ Server, ncol = 1)
})
# patchwork
wrap_plots(gg_l, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

You can combine the plots also manually, have a look [here](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/assembly.html). I used the OP's data for `df`.