# Put legend under each facet using facet_grid; adding one title and one caption to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with a plot analogous to the following:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=carb)) +
geom_line() + facet_grid(gear ~ .) + 
ggtitle(expression("Title")) +
labs(caption = "Sources: Compustat, Author's Calculations") + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5), 
plot.caption=element_text(size=8, hjust=.5),
strip.background = element_blank(), 
strip.text = element_blank(), 
legend.title = element_blank())
```

I'm trying to do the following:

- Insert a legend beneath each of the 3 facets, each legend specific to the facet above it.
- Insert one plot title (as opposed to the same title above each facet).
- Insert one caption beneath the final facet (as opposed to three captions beneath each facet).

I was able to reproduce [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840542/place-a-legend-for-each-facet-wrap-grid-in-ggplot2) example on assigning a legend to each facet.
However, the plot title was placed above and the caption below each facet. Also, this example uses facet_wrap and not facet_grid.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tempgg <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  do(gg = {ggplot(data=., aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=carb)) +
      geom_point() + 
      labs(x = NULL) +
      guides(color = guide_colorbar(title.position = "left")) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5), 
            plot.caption=element_text(size=8, hjust=.5),
            legend.position = "bottom")}) 

tempgg$gg[1][[1]] <- tempgg$gg[1][[1]] + labs(title = "Top title")
tempgg$gg[3][[1]] <- tempgg$gg[3][[1]] + labs(x = "Axis label", caption = "Bottom caption")

tempgg %>% gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = .$gg)
```

[image]

This isn't the most elegant way to do it. Each of the three grobs gets an equal space when you `grid.arrange` them, so the first and last ones are squished from the title and caption taking up space. You could add something like `heights = c(3,2,3)` inside the `grid.arrange` call, but you'd have to fiddle with each of the heights to get it to look right, and even then it would be a visual approximation, not exact.

To do it the more precise way, you'd need to look at the underlying gtables in each of the grobs. https://stackoverflow.com/users/471093/baptiste is the expert on that.

---

## Update:

I used a @baptiste solution, which is still not particularly elegant, but gives you the same plot space for each panel. Use this snippet in place of the last line above.

```
tempggt <- tempgg %>% do(ggt = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(.$gg))) %>% .$ggt
gg1 <- tempggt[[1]]
gg2 <- tempggt[[2]]
gg3 <- tempggt[[3]]

gridExtra::grid.arrange(gridExtra::rbind.gtable(gg1, gg2, gg3))
```