# How to add two (same) legends in ggplot and change legend title and labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add two (same) legends in ggplot and also want to change legend title and labels. I have tried this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = len, color=factor(dose), fill= factor(dose))) +
  geom_density(alpha=0.4) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "khaki1", colour = "darkorchid3", size = 2, linetype = "solid"),
      panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'solid', colour = "white"),
      panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid', colour = "white"),
      plot.background = element_rect(fill = "bisque2"),
      text = element_text(colour="blue4"), axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.25)), axis.text = element_text(colour="blue4", size = 12),
      legend.position=c(.90,.85), legend.background = 
      element_rect(fill="lightsalmon", colour = "tomato3", size = 1.25),
      legend.title = element_text(colour="navy", face="bold"),
      legend.text = element_text( colour="midnightblue", face="bold"), strip.background = element_rect(fill="olivedrab1", colour = "darkorchid3", size = 2, linetype = "solid"), 
      strip.text = element_text(colour="coral4", size=12,  angle=0, face="bold")) +
   scale_fill_discrete(name = "Dose", labels = c("A", "B", "C")) +
   facet_wrap(~supp)
```

but I got this plot:
[image]

I want this plot:
[image]

Can somebody help me? Thank you.

Comment: what about [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840542/place-a-legend-for-each-facet-wrap-grid-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @erocoar and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840542/place-a-legend-for-each-facet-wrap-grid-in-ggplot2) have suggested, `grid.arrange` from `gridExtra` is useful here. Borrowing heavily from from the linked question:

```
library(gridExtra)
out <- by(data = ToothGrowth, INDICES = ToothGrowth$supp, FUN = function(m) {
    m <- droplevels(m)
    m <- ggplot(m, aes(x = len, fill= factor(dose)), color=factor(dose)) + 
    geom_density(alpha=0.4) +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "khaki1", colour = "darkorchid3", 
                                      size = 2, linetype = "solid"),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'solid', 
                                      colour = "white"),
          panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid', 
                                      colour = "white"),
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = "bisque2"),
          text = element_text(colour="blue4"), 
          axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.25)), 
          axis.text = element_text(colour="blue4", size = 12),
          legend.position=c(.90,.85), 
          legend.background = element_rect(fill="lightsalmon",
                              colour = "tomato3", size = 1.25),
          legend.title = element_text(colour="navy", face="bold"),
          legend.text = element_text( colour="midnightblue", face="bold"), 
          strip.background = element_rect(fill="olivedrab1", 
                                      colour = "darkorchid3", size = 2, 
                                      linetype = "solid"), 
          strip.text = element_text(colour="coral4", size=12,  angle=0, 
                                face="bold")) +
   scale_fill_discrete(name = "Dose", labels = c("A", "B", "C")) +
   xlim(0,35) +
   ylim(0,0.2) +
   ggtitle(m$supp)
})
do.call(grid.arrange, list(grobs = out, ncol = 2))
```

Some things to note.

- I moved the `color` argument outside of the `aes()` call and this removed the extra legend.
- I manually set the x and y limits for a consistent look.
- I needed to add a title.
- To get the plots side by side I had to add a second argument to `do.call()`. When supplying more than one argument it needs to be in a list.

I hope this helps.