# Boxplot comparison of multiple dataset using facet_wrap functionality of ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, tidyverse, boxplot

I have a `data.frame` like below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(129)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2005-12-31"), by = "month"),
                 O1 = runif(60,1,5), R1 = runif(60,1,5), C1 = runif(60,1,5),
                 O2 = runif(60,1,5), R2 = runif(60,1,5), C2 = runif(60,1,5),
                 O3 = runif(60,1,5), R3 = runif(60,1,5), C3 = runif(60,1,5))
```

**Target:**

I would like to produced a 3 `facet` `boxplot`, where `facet` one be comparing dataset of `O1, R1, and C1`. On `facet 2`, i would like to see `boxplot` for `O2, R2, and C2`, and likewise for the 3rd `facet`.

**Example:**

I am looking for a `plot` like attached. the example plot is `2 facet` while I am looking for a `3 facet`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update:

```
DF1 <- DF %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Date= ymd(Date)) %>% 
  mutate(month = month(Date),
         year = year(Date)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(Date, month, year)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(facet = case_when(name %in% c("O1", "R1", "C1") ~ "facet1",
                           name %in% c("O2", "R2", "C2") ~ "facet2",
                           name %in% c("O3", "R3", "C3") ~ "facet3")) 

  ggplot(DF1, aes(x=factor(month), y=value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=name)) +
  facet_wrap(.~facet, nrow = 3)
```

[image]

First answer:
Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -Date
  ) %>% 
  mutate(facet = case_when(name %in% c("O1", "R1", "C1") ~ "facet1",
                           name %in% c("O2", "R2", "C2") ~ "facet2",
                           name %in% c("O3", "R3", "C3") ~ "facet3")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(.~facet, nrow = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Sort of @TarJae. Each `facet` should compare the dataset across months. That means, `Facet1` should compare data for `O1,R1, and C1` for all the months of the year. Likewise, Facet should have a comparative `boxplot` for `O2,R2,and C2`.

Comment: Next try. please see my update!

Comment: Exactly- what i wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DF %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Date) %>% 
  mutate(month = factor(month.abb[month(Date)], month.abb),
         groups = readr::parse_number(name)) %>% 
  group_by(groups) %>% 
  mutate(facet_groups = paste0(unique(name), collapse = ","),
         name = fct_reorder(name, groups)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(facet_groups ~ .,
             ncol = 1) +
  labs(y = "Monthly Precipitation",
       x = element_blank(),
       fill = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: If you're interested in having a unique legend per facet then I would suggest you check out this SO question using the gridExtra library where you `grid.arrange` your plots instead of using `facet_wrap`: [Place a legend for each facet_wrap grid in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840542/place-a-legend-for-each-facet-wrap-grid-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Many thanks for looking into this and providing alternative solution to my question.