# How to use facet_wrap to make subplots have their own legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use `facet_wrap` in a way that it allows every subplot have their own legend depending on the e.g. max and min values within each subplot.

When I do:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg, col = hp)) +
        geom_point() +
        scale_color_viridis_c() +
        facet_wrap(. ~ hp)
```

I get:

[image]

But, the problem here is that I get a common legend, which I do not want. How can I use `facet_wrap` (or any other technique that I may not know) to make subplots have their own legend?

Comment: I don't think you can have separate legends with faceting, it's often considered one of faceting's "strengths" (efficiencies). You should be able to do something similar with the `patchwork` package, albeit with a little more control on your part.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840542/place-a-legend-for-each-facet-wrap-grid-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Place a legend for each facet\_wrap grid in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840542/place-a-legend-for-each-facet-wrap-grid-in-ggplot2)