# create separate legend for each row of facet_grid

Tags: ggplot2, legend, facet-wrap, facet-grid, ggpubr

I am using `nested_facet()` to plot a large number of experiments, yielding a 9x6 array. Each panel in the array is a stacked bargraph with variables indicated by color, same set of variables common to each row.

My code...

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=enzyme_drug, y=counts, fill = species)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=1)) +
  facet_grid(pH ~ combo, scales = "free")
```

The only problem with putting them all together into a facet grid is that the number of variables indicated by color in the figure legend is too high, resulting in adjacent colors that are hard to differentiate.

An easy way out of this would be to create a separate legend for each row, with the small number of variables for each row being much easier to differentiate.

Any ideas on how to do this?

The other alternative I realise is to loop the creation of separate `facet_grids` into a list and then put them together with `ggarrange()` - this yields unwieldy x-axis labels repeated for each row, although I could remove the x-axes manually for each row in the arrangement there must be a simpler method?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Place a legend for each facet\_wrap grid in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840542/place-a-legend-for-each-facet-wrap-grid-in-ggplot2)

Comment: and to your question with removing the x axis labels and generating a list of plots - To my knowledge this is currently not possible in an automated "simple" fashion.